# How do I inject an instance of an objct into the "create" function of .NET Core DI Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

When instantiating a class from the `IServiceProvider.GetService` I want to inject an instance that I created earlier in the request into the create function.

```
var transintObject = new SomeObjec();
var other = serviceProvider.GetService<RegisterdService>(transientObject)
```

I know `RegisterdService` is dependent on `SomeObject` but right now I'm not able to register the construction of the `SomeObject` in the DIContainer.

Comment: That can only be done when registering the service using the factory delegate

Comment: What is `SomeObjec`? Does it represent data? Or is it a service?

Comment: In my case it is data, collected from the "environment" (http request)

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed using the `Activatorutilities.CreateInstance`